# Update record in firebase storage visible only after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

When editing a record in my collection in firebase and change the image, it will successfully update in Firebase and in Google Cloud Platform (storage), but in the template I am not able to see the change unless I refresh the page. The error I get is: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

```
router.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  firebase.database().ref(`collection/` + id).once('value')
    .then(function(data) {
      res.render('myEditTemplate', {
        id: id,
        collectionRecords: data.val()
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      res.render('error', {
        error: error
      });
    });
});

router.post('/edit', upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  var name = req.body.name;
  var image = req.file;

  if (!req.file) {
    console.log('no image has been uploaded');

    firebase.database().ref(`collection/` + id).update({
      'name': name,
    });
  } else {
    console.log('image successfully uploaded');

    var filePath = id + ".jpg";

    fs.rename(req.file.path, filePath, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.render("error", {
          err: err
        });
      }

      var myPath = 'collection/' + filePath;
      var storageFile = bucket.file(myPath);
      var storageFileStream = storageFile.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
          contentType: req.file.mimetype
        }
      });

      storageFileStream.on('error', function(err) {
        return res.render("error", {
          error: err
        });
      });

      storageFileStream.on('finish', function() {
        storageFile.makePublic(function(err, data) {

          if (err) {
            return res.render("error", {
              err: err
            });
          }
        });

        fs.unlink(filePath, function(err) {

          console.error(err);
        });

        firebase.database().ref(`collection/` + id).update({
          'name': name,
          'image_id': filePath
        });
      });
      fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(storageFileStream);
    });
  }
  res.redirect('/collection');
});
```

Comment: When you have the following error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.", it means that you are trying to send a response to the request after one has already been sent. In your case, you are making a redirect before the asynchronous tasks are performed, so whenever you have an error, you are trying to send a second response to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're getting such an error, it means you are sending the response to the client more than once (specifically, *setting the headers*).

The source of the error in this case is the fact you have `res.redirect(...)` and `res.render(...)`.

```
router.post('/edit', upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  var name = req.body.name;
  var image = req.file;
  ...
    // Eventually update the file in Google Cloud Storage
    // This happens in an async way.
  ...

  // This will be always called first
  res.redirect('/collection');
});
```

In case of an error coming from the async operations, you'll get the error you mentioned. It simply fails to render the error template, because you *already* did `redirect(...)`.

Your current timeline looks like this:

```
           ___ Update the image in GC __
          /                             \
|--*-----*--*----------------------------*------>
   |        |                         Is there an error?
 Request    |                             If so, res.render(...)
            |                             Rendering the error template
      res.redirect(...)                   will always fail due to the
            |                             previous res.redirect(...)
            |
            V
     You do not see the new image
     at this moment, because it's
     simply not updated yet.
```

What it should happen is:

```
           ___ Update the image in GC __
          /                             \
|--*-----*-------------------------------*------>
   |                                  Is there an error?
 Request                                If so, show the error: 
                                          res.render(...)
                                        If not, do the redirect:
                                        res.redirect(...)
                                         |
                                         V
                                     Since the page is going to load
                                     *after* the image was updated
                                     you will see the updated image.
```

The code will look like this:

```
router.post('/edit', upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  var name = req.body.name;
  var image = req.file;

  if (!req.file) {
    console.log('no image has been uploaded');
    firebase.database().ref(`collection/` + id).update({
      'name': name,
    }).then(function() {
      res.redirect('/collection');
    }).catch(function(err) {
      res.render("error", {
        err: err
      });
    })
  } else {
    console.log('image successfully uploaded');
    var filePath = id + ".jpg";
    fs.rename(req.file.path, filePath, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.render("error", {
          err: err
        });
      }

      var myPath = 'collection/' + filePath;
      var storageFile = bucket.file(myPath);
      var storageFileStream = storageFile.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
          contentType: req.file.mimetype
        }
      });

      storageFileStream.on('error', function(err) {
        return res.render("error", {
          error: err
        });
      });

      storageFileStream.on('finish', function() {
        storageFile.makePublic(function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            return res.render("error", {
              err: err
            });
          }
          res.redirect('/collection');
        });

        fs.unlink(filePath, function(err) {
          console.error(err);
        });

        firebase.database().ref(`collection/` + id).update({
          'name': name,
          'image_id': filePath
        });
      });
      fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(storageFileStream);
    });
  }
});
```